# How to methodically debug "Uncaught Invariant Violation" errors in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a methodical approach to track down which component is causing the "Uncaught Invariant Violation" errors in an unfamiliar codebase. Specifically when running a karma test suite that does not output stack-traces.

The most luck I had was adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(element))`to the `render` functions e.g. `ReactShallowRenderer.prototype.render`, which works *okay*. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you are using the development version of React it should tell you the source of this error - are you? Do you have access to sourcemaps?

Answer (score 1):

I used Exception breakpoints on chrome, turn on the checkmark. Then use the CallStack to trace back the component throwing the error.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#exceptions